# how to exclude product of all the variables based on condition in python

Tags: python, django

```
import numpy as np
x_1 = getval1
x_2 = getval2
x_3 = getval3
x_4 = getval4
y_1 = getx(x_1)
y_2 = getx(x_2)
y_3 = getx(x_3)
y_4 = getx(x_4)
z_1 = gety(x_1, y_1)
z_2 = gety(x_2, y_2)
z_3 = gety(x_3, y_3)
z_4 = gety(x_4, y_4)
val = np.prod(
    list({float(z_1), float(z_2), float(z_3), float(z_4)}))
```

I have the code as above and im trying to find if  y_1 value is 20 and i get z_1 value from it and assign it to 'val' variable and not to include
other variables like z_2, z_3,z_4 in `np.prod()`.  similarly if y_2 value is 20 i dont want other variables like z_1,z_3,z_4 to include  in 'val' variable. it applies for 
y_3 and y_4 as well

for eg:

```
if y_1 == '20' then val = float(z_1)
```

if then statement is not available in python.is there any other way to check this for y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4 variables?

Comment: `"if then statement is not available in python."` it is if you use correct syntax: `if y_1 == '20': val = float(z_1)`

Comment: You have if statement in python, but don't uses then (the result is exactly the same. You can use **if condition: statement**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for an `if` statement in Python is :

```
if <condition> :
   expr
elif <condition>:
   expr
else:
   expr
```

Comment: can we handle all the four conditions in single if statement like if y_1 or y_2 or y_3 or y_4== '20' and assign different values of float variables?

Comment: You can. Logical operators are 'or', 'and' and 'not'.

Comment: But i do have different expr. In such cases we can not use any operators, correct ?

Comment: or do we have any inbuilt in python to do this ?

Comment: You can add as many expressions as you want, you just have to indent them properly